# Split svmfile matrix into 4 parts

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have two files which I divided into training and testing sets.

```
traindata = load_svmlight_file("training")
testdata = load_svmlight_file("testing")
Xtrain = traindata[0].todense()
ytrain = traindata[1]
Xtest = testdata[0].todense()
ytest = testdata[1]
```

I would like to split my Xtest and ytest into 4 parts:

Xtest1, ytest1
Xtest2, ytest2,
Xtest3, ytest3,
Xtest4, ytest4

My instinct is to use sklearn.train_test_split but I'm not sure. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using [np.array_split](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html):

```
import numpy as np
test=np.arange(21)
xtest1,xtest2,xtest3,xtest4 = np.array_split(np.random.permutation(test),4)
```

I used `np.random.permutation` in case you want the data to split randomly. If you just want to split it into consecutive parts, you can remove the `np.random.permutation`.